# Can't add gitlab CI/CD variables

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

When i try to add a new variable in Settings > CI/CD > variables like :

```
        Key : THIS_IS_A_TEST , value : test
```

In the console i got :

```
        Erreur d’analyse XML : mal formé
        Emplacement : http://__my_domain__/admin/ci/variables
        Numéro de ligne 1, Colonne 5 :
```

When i check in tools/network , i can see that gitlab PATCH Json but the type is XML.

Is there a configuration to to correct this error ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a Firefox issue. Works nice with Chrome.

Comment: Im on Chrome and getting the same result